# Can't Center website

Tags: html, css

How do I center the body? I'm trying to build a 960px web, but when testing it sticks to the left all the time (attached a screenshot).

[image]

How can I fix this? thanks for everyone that can help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
background-color:WHITE;
width: 960px centered;
}

.one {
background: #B1B4B5;
color: BLACK;
font-size: 60px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.two {
background: #B1B4B5;
color: BLACK;
font-size: 60px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 900px;
text-align: center;
}

.three{
background: #B1B4B5;
color: BLACK;
font-size: 60px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.four {
background: #B1B4B5;
color: BLACK;
font-size: 60px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 900px;
text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="one">1</a>
<a class="two">2</a>
<a class="three">3</a>
<a class="four">4</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to center usually apply margin: 0 auto on the element
body { margin:0 auto;}

Comment: set width and margin: 0 auto; to center an container for any screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, change the `body` rule to:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

There's no `centered` value in `width`.

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/ruhonecifo**

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/L24o7gyu/)

```
body 
{
    background-color: WHITE;
    //incorrect value (width: 960px centered;)
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```